# Introductory texts to formal ontology and mereology?

Tags: metaphysics, reference-request, ontology, philosophy-of-language, mereology

I’m a grad student of Mathematics, doing research in Formal Semantics (a topic in Computational Linguistics) and some of my more tangential reading has made me privy to the existence of formal ontology and mereology as topics. I love bizarre and exotic logics, and was hoping to get some recommendations for introductory texts on these topics that would be appropriate for someone with a heavy background in math and formal logic.

Comment: You will want to look at the [PhD thesis of Maria Keet](http://www.meteck.org/files/AFormalTheoryOfGranularity_CMK08.pdf).

Comment: I'd like to answer this with a link to the SEP article on Logic and Ontology and what seems to be a very strong bibliography: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-ontology/

Comment: I own [Introduction to Mereology](https://books.google.com/books?id=6PS4DgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=introduction+to+mereology&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjKnJ2n1qL-AhUVkYkEHWaVCDAQ6AF6BAgEEAI#v=onepage&q=introduction%20to%20mereology&f=false) and Lando puts forth a mereological theory using formalisms.

Comment: Not an introductory text, but a paper drawing on (a) defeasible logic (b) mereology (c) causal logic. https://appearedtoblogly.files.wordpress.com/2011/05/koons-robert-22a-new-look-at-the-cosmological-argument22.pdf. For formal ontology, you'll also want to review zaltas work on abstracts, he uses coq to prove a number of theorems